# Plotting a function including for loops in R

Tags: r, finance

I'm trying to make a price setting algorithm for european options using R. I've created a function that can output the price of the option based on how many steps we split the timeframe of the option into. My problem is that I need to plot the price of the option as the amount of steps goes up and my function only outputs one price. My function is built up like this:

```
strike=110
startprice = 100
alpha = 0.055
sigma = 0.2
R=1.05
r=0.05
T = 3

CallPrice <- function(n){
  dt = T/n
  u = exp(alpha*dt+sigma*sqrt(dt))
  d = exp(alpha*dt-sigma*sqrt(dt))
  q=(R-d)/(u-d)
  Call = matrix(0,nrow=n+1, ncol = n+1)
  Call[,n+1] <- pmax(startprice*(u^(0:n))*(d^(n:0))-strike,0)
  CallVal <- matrix(0,nrow = n,ncol = 1)


  for (k in n:1){
      for (i in k:1) {
        for (j in 1:i){
          Call[j,i] <- (q*Call[j+1,i+1]+(1-q)*Call[j,i+1])/R
        }
        CallVal[k,1] <- Call[1,1]
      }

  }
  return(CallVal)
}

CallPrice(n)
```

My expectation was that I could just set n to an interval when plotting and the function would repeat but I get the error I 0:n : numerical expression has 10 elements: only the first used. So I don't see how I should be able to plot this.

Comment: did you check the class of n?

Comment: Use sapply to get the values to plot

Comment: sapply seems to be a step in the right direction! Thank you :D